# Rename action in Microsoft Endpoint Manager (Intune) not working

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-intune

I have performed a device **Rename action** in Endpoint manager through its MS Graph Rename API and got success message but the device name is still unchanged.

API : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-devices-manageddevice-setdevicename?view=graph-rest-beta

**Timeline:**

1. Previous Device name : MACHINE-W10-10
2. Attempted to rename Device to MACHINE-W10-11
3. Endpoint manager said success
4. Waited more than 24 hours but name is still unchanged

[image]

Comment: outside of your code, did you try the API call with Graph explorer or POSTMAN as well? What's the response you received?

Comment: I tried in postman and got 204, which is the expected response for success.